# How to pass element of ArrayList<Integer[]> to method that takes only arrays?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList whose elements are arrays. For example `[[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]`.  I need to pass the array element, ex `[1,2,3]`, to a method that takes only arrays.

```
public ArrayList<Integer[]> arrayList;
//some code
for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
  Integer[] elementArray = arraylist.get(i);
  Integer = methodTakesOnlyArrays(elementArray);
  // more code...
```

this returns a `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;`

How do I correct this?

Thanks

Comment: Can we see how `arrayList` gets filled?  This looks like it should work as-is.

Comment: I think 'some code' has mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the fact that your code contains some syntax errors, the following code compiles and executes correctly:

```
public void first(){
    ArrayList<Integer[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
    arrayList.add(new Integer[]{2,3,4});
    arrayList.add(new Integer[]{5,6,7});
    arrayList.add(new Integer[]{8,9,10});
    //some code
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
      Integer[] elementArray = arrayList.get(i);
      Integer integer = methodTakesOnlyArrays(elementArray);
      // more code...

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. Louis and Kayser your suspicions were correct. There was an upsteam problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I have write some code like you have described, it runs just right. I am using JDK1.6.0_32.

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
    Integer[] elementArrayA = { 1, 2, 3 };
    Integer[] elementArrayB = { 4, 5, 6 };

    arrayList.add(elementArrayA);
    arrayList.add(elementArrayB);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); ++i) {
        Integer[] elementArray = arrayList.get(i);
        System.out.println(arrayToString(elementArray));
    }
}

public static String arrayToString(Integer[] inputArray) {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    stringBuffer.append("[");

    boolean isFirst = true;
    for (Integer elementInteger : inputArray) {
        if (isFirst) {
            stringBuffer.append(String.valueOf(elementInteger));
            isFirst = false;
        } else {
            stringBuffer.append(", ");
            stringBuffer.append(String.valueOf(elementInteger));
        }
    }

    stringBuffer.append("]");

    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<Integer[]> arrayList; 
//initialize the arrays and add them to the arraylist 
for(Integer[] in : arrayList) {  
  Integer result = methodTakesOnlyArrays(in); 
  // more code... 
}
```